# How to delete all photos from the iOS 7 camera roll WITHOUT importing them?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, ios

- I have 4000 photos in the camera roll
- I don't want import them into my MacBook's [iPhoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhoto) or nowhere, so
- simple want delete them directly in the iPhone (iOS 7).
- selecting them one-by-one (you sure agree) is NOT very user friendly

What is the "Apple way" of doing this (usually) *simple* thing?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## On iOS 7

1. Open the Photos App and make sure you are in the “Photos” section from the three icons at the bottom of the screen;
2. Look at the top of the screen and make sure the view is “Moments;”
3. Now you can tap individual thumbnails one at a time to select them, or you can tap the word “Select” that appears at the top of each grouping to select an entire grouping.

---

## On iOS 6

1. Go to Settings → General → Usage → Photos & Camera;
2. Swipe on the “Camera Roll” entry;
3. A “Delete” button appears.

This solution does *not* work on iOS 7 (last tested on iOS 7.0.4). It is probably a bug.

---

## Any iOS, but using a computer

If you have iOS 7, you can use Image Capture on your Mac to delete photos from the iPhone without importing them:

1. Plug the iPhone to your Mac with the iPhone cable;
2. Quit iPhoto if it launches automatically;
3. Launch Image Capture;
4. Select the photos you want to delete;
5. Click the red icon to delete the photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 GREAT answer - helped me delete the unwanted photos. But still not solved the problem, doing this directly in the iPhone without a computer...

Comment: I found the solution on iOS 6 (and earlier probably, though I did not test). Go to Settings -> General -> Usage -> Photos & Camera. Then swipe on the Camera Roll entry, a Delete button will appear. This does *not* work on iOS 7.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution on iOS 7, but I don't think there's one. Obviously the iOS 6 solution should work. Apple probably forgot to add in the “Photos & Camera” usage page the “Edit” button that can be found for instance in the “Music” usage page.

Comment: Simple, i can't understand why apple don't add a feature what is implemented in any basic camera.... Thanx anyway for the partial solution - accepting...

Comment: There is a way of doing this on iOS7 by selecting entire collections at a time and deleting them this way. See here: http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/iphoneandipodtouchapps/qt/Select-Photos-Ios7.htm

Comment: At the moment I'm testing iOS 7.1 beta 5 and it's still not fixed if it's a bug as mentioned(it's highly unlikely but maybe because of some weird reason Apple wants it the it is right now). Perhaps I should inform Apple about it.

Comment: You should inform Apple, but should not discuss this here; you're under NDA dude! ;)

Comment: ImageCapture FTW!

Comment: ImageCapture on OS X El Capitain and iPhone 6 connected shows a 'prohibited button' - but it is not red. I kinda missed it because I was looking for a 'red' button somewhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

Works on ios7 - Plug your iphone into your computer and open it via My Computer - then find the photos file(s). Select all and then delete! Done!

Comment: "My Computer" is a Windows thing.   On Sep 25, he wanted a solution directly on the iPhone, not using a computer.