# How can I mass delete photos off my camera roll (iOS7)

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos, ios

There are about 700 photos on my Camera Roll that I don't want.

1) I don't want to delete them one-by-one
2) usage > camera and photos > side swipe camera roll and delete does NOT work on iOS7.
3) I tried using Image Capture on my computer, and my device shows up on the left, but there are no image files.

I'm going crazy, there has to be an easy way to do this.

Comment: I was going for a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103172/how-to-delete-all-photos-from-the-ios-7-camera-roll-without-importing-them, but you tried Image Capture. Does the Camera Roll shows up empty in iPhoto too?

Comment: Anyway there seems to be a flaw of design in iOS 7 which does not allow mass-deletion of photos directly from the device. You can report a bug on http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternate way.

1)connect device to MAC.

2)import the photos that you don't want and after import it will ask to "Keep original or remove".

3)select remove from device.(this is what you want)

4)then you can remove from MAC also.