# Easiest way to delete NON-Album photos from iphone camera roll

Tags: photos, macos

What is the easiest way to delete photos from Camera Roll that I haven't put in an album?

Answer (score 1):

Click Select from the right upper corner, select the photos you want deleted and click delete.

Comment: You might want to read the question again "Non Album"

Comment: This method does work for the Camera Roll (which counts as 'Non Album'). Nonetheless, an even faster method is listed here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103176/22432